# Какое наилучшее место для размещения админ панели?

Tags: безопасность, администрирование, админка

Предположим есть интернет магазин, работающий на виртуальном сервере (VDS, VPS). К нему есть соответствующая админ панель, где войдя по логину и паролю администратор может просматривать статистические данные магазина, а также производить настройки вебсайта.
Где лучше разместить админ панель? Какие у каждого подхода плюсы и минусы? Лично я вижу три варианта:

1. Сделать поддиректорию в рабочей директории сайта. (типа /admin/admin.php)
2. Создать на сервере виртуальный хостинг с доступом по отдельному домену.
3. Поднять еще один сервер (с отдельным IP), попутно разделить Базы Данных настроить доступ к локальной БД и к БД самого интернет магазина.

Есть ли еще подходы, просьба озвучить, даже если описать подход вы не можете.

Comment: У нас наружу только vpn смотрит. Всё остальное только или из локалки или никак.

Comment: @don Rumata немного не понял, что значит vpn наружу смотрит

Comment: Ну т.е. если просканить из интернета каким-нить `nmap`, то будет доступен только порт от vpn. Всё остальное будет `closed`.